# Show $N(0, a^2) \cdot c = N(0, a^2c^2)$

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $\xi$ is a continuous random variable such that $\xi$ ~ $N(a,b)$ normal distribution. How to show that
$$N(0, a^2) \cdot c = N(0, a^2c^2)$$

I found $$\mathbb E\xi_{N(0, a^2)} = \mathbb E\xi_{N(0, a^2c^2)} = 1$$
and $$D\xi_{N(0,a^2)} = a^4, D\xi_{N(0,a^2c^2)} = c^4a^4$$

What does this show? That is, it is clear that the coefficient $c$ must be introduced into the distribution to the second degree, but this is not visible here. How else can you prove equality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your choice of notation is clumsy, which is why you are confused.

it is sloppy and misleading to write something like $$N(0, a^2) c = N(0, a^2 c^2).$$  Instead, we should define random variables, and then perform computations on those random variables.  Specifically, suppose $$X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 0, \sigma^2 = a^2),$$ that is to say, $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu = 0$ and variance $\sigma^2 = a^2$.  Thus $X$ has probability density $$f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} a} e^{-x^2/(2a^2)}, \quad -\infty < x < \infty,$$ and cumulative distribution function $$F_X(x) = \Pr[X \le x] = \Phi(x) = \int_{t = -\infty}^x f_X(t) \, dt = \int_{t = -\infty}^x \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} a} e^{-t^2/(2a^2)} \, dt.$$

Now let $Y = cX$ with $c \ne 0$.  Then $$F_Y(y) = \Pr[Y \le y] = \Pr[cX \le y] = \Pr[X \le y/c] = F_X(y/c),$$ if $c > 0$, and if $c < 0$, we have $$F_Y(y) = \Pr[cX \le y] = \Pr[X \ge y/c] = 1 - F_X(y/c).$$  In both cases, differentiating with respect to $y$ yields $$f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy}\left[F_X(y/c)\right] = f_X(y/c) \cdot \frac{1}{c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} a c} e^{-(y/c)^2/(2a^2)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} (ac)} e^{-y^2/(2(ac)^2)}.$$  Thus $Y$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $(ac)^2$.

All of this is a special case of the more general **location-scale** transformation $$Y = c(X + d) \implies Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu + d, \sigma^2 c^2).$$  This is also the basis of standardizing normal random variables to have zero mean and unit variance, via the choice $d = -\mu$, $c = 1/\sigma$, thus if $X$ is normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ in general, the transformation $$Y = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$$ makes $Y$ a standard normal random variable with zero mean and unit variance.

Answer (score 0):

If $\xi \sim N(0, a^{2})$ then $c\xi$ has normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $E(c^{2}\xi^{2})=c^{2} var(\xi)=c^{2}a^{2}$. Hence $c \xi \sim N(0, c^{2}a^{2})$.

Comment: Why can we do this $\xi$ ~ $N(0, a^2)c$, then $\xi c$ ~ $N(0, a^2)$? And if we had $\xi$ ~ $N(0, a^2)c + b$, what would we do here